# express empty value when on post request

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to post a request to my server but when the server receives the request I display it and I noticed that the request is empty.

code server side:

```
const express=require('express');
const app=express();
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listining at 3000'))
app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(express.json({ limit: '1mb' }))
///routting 


app.post('/api', (req, res) => {  
    console.log("ok");
    console.log(req.body);
 })
```

client side:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>   heloo express <h1>
  <div id="22f"></div>
  <div id="12f"></div>
  <script>
    //get my location
    if ('geolocation' in navigator) {
       console.log("yeeeey")
       navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
          const lat={"lat": position.coords.latitude}
          const lon={"lon":position.coords.longitude}
          const doc=document.getElementById("22f")
          doc.textContent=position.coords.latitude
          const loc=document.getElementById("12f")
          loc.textContent=position.coords.longitude

          const data = { lat, lon };
          console.log(data)
          console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
          const option= {
             method: 'POST',
             body:JSON.stringify(data),
             header: {
                "Content-Type": "aplication/json"
             }
          }
          fetch('/api',option);
       })
     } else {
       console.log("booooo")
     }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this what the server shows me :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the build-in `bodyParser` from express.

Add this line above your endpoints

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
```

As @SuleymanSah has mentioned, the correct build-in middleware is

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: You have a comment like this in the first answer "no need to add an external module anymore. Since v4, express has the bodyParser as a build-it functionality."  But strangely you give the same answer. What's that?

Comment: I didn't give the same answer. Since version 4, express has this module as build-in functionality. You don't have to install and import  `body-parser`. All you have to do is to use the `bodyParser` from express.

Comment: Better to use only `app.use(express.json());`

Comment: yes indeed, that's the correct middleware, I'm editing that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the npm package "body-parser" to be able to read req.body

```
var express = require('express')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

var app = express()

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
```

Comment: no need to add an external module anymore. Since v4, express has the `bodyParser` as a build-it functionality.